# Multi Part/Form-data action request is not working on iPhone Liferay 7

Tags: iphone, portlet, liferay-7, bad-request

Hello i am having custom user profile portlet in which i am updating user detail, user password and user profile picture. I can do all this operation successfully from desktop, android phone and iPhone 7, but from iPhone6/6s or iPad i am getting bad request (400) error from the server if i only change/edit the input fields, All works fine if i upload new image and change/edit other fields.

I am using Lifeary CE GA 5, tomcat bundle.

I don't have any clue how to debug this, any help would be appreciate.

Thanks,
Dipti

Comment: A 400 leaves evidence behind somewhere, either in the liferay logs, the apache logs, whatever.  We certainly can't help debug your environment because we won't have access.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have a sample portlet if you can debug.

Comment: Hi @Dipti, did you find a solution? We have a similar problem with the same Liferay version and iphone 6. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Denis.Kipchakbaev i didn't find any solution yet. Please let me know if you find any workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case the problem was in the submit button. It was defined as an anchor with jQuery submit() in onClick action. We changed it to regular `<button type="submit" ...>` and the problem with iphone has gone. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I too have a jQuery submit() in onClick action because i have a 2 actions within same form, any solution for this?

Comment: @Dipti, maybe try to intercept form submit with a script putting preventDefault() and your logic. Sorry can't help you much here...

Comment: Humm, did that way only still not working working on it to find the solution.

Comment: it's worked when i make auth_taken false in my portlet component.